# How to echo billing phone number under My Account in Woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, user-meta

We're wish to get customer's `billing_phone` number & then put it under "My Account" or "My Address" section.

This way, our billing support can look up for a number to call from the front-end, w/o navigating into order management.

Tried using `phone' => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_phone', true )` in my-address.php, but that isn't working.

Any leads? Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're close - just need to tweak your arguments:

```
<?php echo get_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_phone', true ) ?>
```

Just make sure `$customer_id` is the ID of the user - you probably want [`get_current_user_id()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_user_id) instead.

Comment: so correct code is `<?php echo get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'billing_phone', true ) ?>` which works well. Put it anywhere you want.